# Change class on mouseover and scroll dependent on offset

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive, which resizes the navbar on scroll.

This works fine, but when I hover the mouse over the navbar, I want to to remove/add a class depending on the offset. However, this doesn't seem to be happening with the code below. How do I fix it?

```
angular.module('marquesslondonApp')
  .directive('navbarShrink', function ($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        offset: '@',
        scrollClass: '@'
      },
      link: function (scope, element) {
        angular.element($window).bind('scroll', function () {
          if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(scope.offset)) {
            element.addClass(scope.scrollClass);
          } else {
            element.removeClass(scope.scrollClass);
          }
        });
        angular.element.on('mouseenter', function () {
          if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(scope.offset)) {
            element.removeClass(scope.scrollClass);
          }
        });
        angular.element.on('mouseleave', function () {
          if (this.pageYOffset >= parseInt(scope.offset)) {
            element.addClass(scope.scrollClass);
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

This is the element I am targeting:

```
<div navbar-shrink offset="50" scroll-class="navbar-shrink" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
              <img src="images/logo.png">
            </a>
    </div>

    <div style="display: block">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar">
          <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">TAILORING</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/process">Process</a></li>
              <li><a href="/look">Our Look</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a ng-href="/lifestyle">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="/story">STORY</a></li>
          <li><a ng-href="/contact">GET IN TOUCH</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-top: 6.5em;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.navbar-shrink .navbar-nav {
  display: none;
}
.navbar-shrink.navbar {
  height: 6em;
}
.navbar-shrink.navbar>.container>.navbar-header>.navbar-brand img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 44px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>.active, {
  color: #808ba0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
  color: #808ba0;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#navbar-header {
  transition: 2s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgba(51, 55, 65, 0.9);
}
.navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
  background-color: rgba(51, 55, 65, 0.9);
}
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  height: 10.5em;
  -webkit-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: height 300ms ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: fixed !important;
}
.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-brand img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 44px;
}
.nav {
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing exactly? Is the class not added or not removed? What happens when you move the mouse on the element?

Comment: On scroll, the class is added/removed. On mouseenter and mouseleave, it isnt

Comment: You are only attempted to remove the class on mouseenter and add it on leave. If you enter and then leave right away there will be no change. Is the class already on the element when you mouse over the element? And then it is not removed if you keep the mouse over the element?

Comment: If the user has scrolled down the page, then the navbar-shrink class will be on the element and entering the element should remove it, leaving the element should bring it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive `link` function, you need to set the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event listeners on `element`, not `angular.element`.

So replace `angular.element.on('mouseenter', ...)` and `angular.element.on('mouseleave', ...)` with `element.on('mouseenter', ...)` and `element.on('mouseleave', ...)`.